# Create a google friendly header with text and logo

Tags: customization, headers, seo

I want to customize my current header in wordpress and include a logo in it. The following solution works:

```
<header class="site-header">
<div class="wrap">
<a href="<?=get_bloginfo('home'); ?>" alt="<?php print get_bloginfo('name') .' - '. get_bloginfo('description'); ?>">
<img src="<?=get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/mypage-logo.png" title="<?php print get_bloginfo('name') .' - '. get_bloginfo('description'); ?>"></a>
</div>
</header>
```

But as this does not include any `<h1>`-Tag is this a Google friendly solution? I could create an `<h1>` and reposition it via `position` or `text-indent`, but is this Google friendly either?

Does anybody has a recommendation?

Thanks!

Comment: I would save the h1 for the page or post title. Don't bother with it for your logo/site name.

Answer (score 0):

So far i know google appreciate a single instance of h1 tag in a page, but it could be anywhere at the priority content area. And all of WordPress front pages does have an element to use inside h1, such as post title, category name, search text, author name etc.

Usually Blog or Front page doesn't have a Headline or title. So you could try adding it for the front page only.

```
<?php
$tag = 'div';
if( is_home() || is_front_page() ){
$tag = 'h1';
} ?>
<header class="site-header">
<<?php echo $tag; ?> class="wrap">
...other code...
</<?php echo $tag; ?>>
</header>
```